# How to delete particular elements in XML from perl

Tags: perl, xslt

As I need to delete the particular element `element1 and element 2` if the same as an empty contents.

eg:

```
 <severaltags>
   ...
   <element1><element2/></element1>
   ...
 <severaltags>
```

Here `element 1` is empty and also `element 2` hence I need to remove the particularly those two elements `element1` and `element2`.

Can anyone could you please help on this one:

And I have searched and tried from the below code but not success.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->new->parse_fh(*DATA);
for ( $xml->findnodes("//*") )
{
    $_->parentNode->removeChild($_)
    unless $_->textContent() =~ /\S/
    or $_->hasAttributes();
}
print $xml->serialize(1);
```

Comment: element1 isn't emtpy, it contains element2.

Comment: @choroba: Accepted. When there is element2 is also empty then please consider the element 1 is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove all empty element2's, then remove empty element1's, as the ones that originally contained element2's should be now included.

You can specify the emptiness in XPath directly:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(location => '1.xml');
for my $element_name (qw( element2 element1 )) {
    for my $element ($xml->findnodes("//$element_name"
                                     . '[not(text() | * | @*)]')
    ) {
        $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
    }
}

print $xml->serialize(1);
```

Comment: `my $xml = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(location => '1.xml');` how to load `xml content` instead of `xml file`.

Comment: @ssr1012: Check the [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML)'s documentation: you can specify `location`, `IO`, or `string`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.

Comment: That would delete empty `<element2>` elements anywhere, when it may be that they must be kept outside of `<element1>` elements.